# UUID in Mountain Lion

Tags: external-hard-drive, osx-mountain-lion, uuid

I am trying to find my external HDD UUID in Mountain Lion but diskutil info /dev/disk1s1 returns:

```
Najis-MacBook-Air:~ ****$ diskutil info disk1s1
   Device Identifier:        disk1s1
   Device Node:              /dev/disk1s1
   Part of Whole:            disk1
   Device / Media Name:      Untitled 1

   Volume Name:              My Book
   Escaped with Unicode:     My%FF%FE%20%00Book

   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /Volumes/My Book
   Escaped with Unicode:     /Volumes/My%FF%FE%20%00Book

   File System Personality:  NTFS
   Type (Bundle):            ntfs
   Name (User Visible):      Windows NT File System (NTFS)

   Partition Type:           Windows_NTFS
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 USB
   SMART Status:             Not Supported

   Total Size:               2.0 TB (2000364240896 Bytes) (exactly 3906961408 512-Byte-Blocks)
   Volume Free Space:        212.5 GB (212506509312 Bytes) (exactly 415051776 512-Byte-Blocks)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Yes
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    No
   Internal:                 No
```

And there is no UUID. What is wrong exactly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually

```
diskutil info disk?s?
```

doesn't provide UUID but using the following does:

```
diskutil info /Volumes/YOUR_DRIVE_NAME
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 1,000 times.

Answer (score 2):

On my Mac (Mountain Lion) actually both commands

```
diskutil info disk?s?
```

and

```
diskutil /Volumes/YOUR_DRIVE_NAME
```

provide the same information. Note that a FAT (MS_DOS) formatted volume
does not have an UUID. If you format it to Mac OSX Extended format, it will!

Comment: My linux box sees some strange 8-letter "UUID"'s for vfat volumes. Is it possible to get them here?

Comment: `$ diskutil /Volumes/MINISD8` and I got 
`diskutil: did not recognize verb "/Volumes/MINISD8"; type "diskutil" for a list`

Answer (score 1):

The drive you are trying to access is of Windows_NTFS Partition Type. So it doesnt show the UDID of the drive. For further accessing of the drive follow the steps given in this old [blog( which shows steps with respect to 10.6)](http://blog.fosketts.net/2010/11/29/write-windows-ntfs-drive-mac-os-106-snow-leopard/), but would serve your purpose as the MAC OSX never changes its backend core.